# Which characters in My Hero Academia can fly?

Tags: my-hero-academia

As far as I remember most characters in My Hero Academia can't fly. I suppose some might be able to do it, but as far as I remember I've only seen a Noumu with wings or Ectoplasm "ghosts" flying. Which characters in My Hero Academia can fly?

Comment: Do you mean "can fly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flight](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Flight) is a quirk possessed by [Christopher Skyline](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Christopher_Skyline), who appears in the spin-off manga [Vigilante - My Hero Academia: Illegals](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Vigilante_-_My_Hero_Academia:_Illegals)

Aside from him a hero with wings called [Hawks](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Hawks) appeared in chapter 184 (the latest chapter as of now). We can assume from his name and appereance that he's able to fly, but we haven't seen him in action yet.

We've also seen a [kid with big red demonic wings](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/File:Demon_Wing_Quirk.png) in a flashback, but we don't know anything about him.

Comment: Hawks is the new no. 2 Hero btw.

Comment: Girls that can manipulate wind that one group with lumilleon, I can't remember her name, also can flying by manipulating winds ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

Some characteres which werent mentioned in the former post

- Air Jet
- Inasa Yoarashi

  > Fumikage learns how to fly in the manga

And some who can levitate

- Bakugo
- Uraraka

  > Endeavor is shown in the manga to be able to levitate
- All for One

Answer (score 0):

HAWKS

Christopher

ALL MIGHT

ENDEAVOR

Nejire

Ryuko

LOUD

Gran Torino

Fumikage

MEZO

SETSUNA

INASA

MONOMA

SEN

NANA

IZUKU

Starservant

HOOD